# How to copy large number of data from one table to another in same database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have two tables with same column structure in the same database: `TableA` and `TableB`.

`TableA` doesn't have any indexes, but `TableB` has a non-clustered unique index.

`TableA` has 290 Million rows of data that needs to be copied to `TableB`.

As they both have same structure, I've tried

```
INSERT INTO TableB 
    SELECT * 
    FROM TableA;
```

It was executing for hours and produced a huge log file that filled the disk. As a result the disk ran out of space and the query was killed.

I can shrink the log file. How can I copy these many rows of data to another table efficiently?

Comment: Check this out may be it will help you . http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/99367/insert-into-table-select-from-table-vs-bulk-insert

Comment: For copying 290 million rows you are going to want to break this up into chunks. Not sure how much data is in each row but when you do this in a single statement it has to log ALL of the data so it can rollback if there is an error. Breaking this into chunks or using BulkInsert will ease the pressure on the logs as it won't require so much data per transaction.

Comment: Do you have a primary key column, if yes what data type is it ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, disable the index on `TableB` before inserting the rows. You can do it using T-SQL:

```
ALTER INDEX IX_Index_Name ON dbo.TableB DISABLE;
```

Make sure to disable all the constraints (foreign keys, check constraints, unique indexes) on your destination table.

Re-enable (and rebuild) them after the load is complete.

Now, there's a couple of approaches to solve the problem:

1. **You have to be OK with a slight chance of data loss**: use the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM ...` syntax you have but switch your database to Bulk-logged recovery mode first ([read before switching](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190203(v=sql.105).aspx)). Won't help if you're already in Bulk-logged or Simple.
2. **With exporting the data first**: you can use the BCP utility to export/import the data. It supports loading data in batches. Read more about using the BCP utility [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx).
3. **Fancy, with exporting the data first:** With SQL 2012+ you can try exporting the data into binary file (using the BCP utility) and load it by using the [BULK INSERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365(v=sql.110).aspx) statement, setting `ROWS_PER_BATCH` option.
4. **Old-school "I don't give a damn" method**: to prevent the log from filling up you will need to perform the
   inserts in batches of rows, not everything at once. If your database
   is running in Full recovery mode you will need to keep log backups
   running, maybe even trying to increase the frequency of the job.

   To batch-load your rows you will need a `WHILE` (don't use them in
   day-to-day stuff, just for batch loads), something like the
   following will work if you have an identifier in the `dbo.TableA`
   table:

   ```
   DECLARE @RowsToLoad BIGINT;
   DECLARE @RowsPerBatch INT = 5000;
   DECLARE @LeftBoundary BIGINT = 0;
   DECLARE @RightBoundary BIGINT = @RowsPerBatch;

   SELECT @RowsToLoad = MAX(IdentifierColumn) dbo.FROM TableA

   WHILE @LeftBoundary < @RowsToLoad
   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO TableB (Column1, Column2)
       SELECT
           tA.Column1,
           tB.Column2
       FROM
           dbo.TableA as tA
       WHERE
           tA.IdentifierColumn > @LeftBoundary
           AND tA.IdentifierColumn <= @RightBoundary

       SET @LeftBoundary = @LeftBoundary + @RowsPerBatch;
       SET @RightBoundary = @RightBoundary + @RowsPerBatch;
   END
   ```

   For this to work effectively you really want to consider creating an
   index on `dbo.TableA (IdentifierColumn)` just for the time you're
   running the load.

Comment: "You have to be OK with a slight chance of data loss" why is there more data loss using `INSERT SELECT` than with `BULK INSERT` or bcp.exe? If it's because of minimal logging, the same applies to all three.

Comment: @Charlieface not always (there are numerous edge-cases where "the same applies to all three" is not true, depending on server/database settings, and other factors). Here's one of the examples (referenced in the doc I've linked under "read before switching"): "When transactional replication is enabled, SELECT INTO and BULK INSERT operations are fully logged even under the Bulk Logged recovery model."

Comment: True, but I'm pretty sure the same is true of bcp.exe as it's also a `BULK` operation (it uses the special `INSERT BULK` command, the same as `SqlBulkCopy` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/88176081-df75-4b24-bcfb-4c16ff03cbfa) I think the differences between when minimal logging vs bulk logging happen will apply whichever method you use.