# Is SqlBulkCopy still required to quickly copy table rows in 2024?

Tags: sql-server

For the simple task of quickly copying all the rows from one database table to another:

```
SELECT ...
INTO dbo.Table
FROM AnotherDB.dbo.Table
```

It seems for the past 15 years the answer has always been to resort to tools external to SQL Server (such as SSIS or SQLBulkCopy, Import / Export Wizard) which seems wasteful in theory - since the data has to leave SQL server (often undergo network or disk I/O) and then come back to it to be bulk inserted.

Have there been no advancements, feature additions, or flags added to SQL that lets us get the benefit of bulk insert (which I understand is linked to reduced transaction logging) without involving any 3rd party tools or infrastructure?

Comment: T-SQL is good for copying data withing the same instance efficiently. External tools facilitate copying data between different instances.

Comment: `select..into..` is already optimised for minimal logging according to the documentation.

Comment: Even regular inserts can benefit from minimal logging in some cases, and SELECT INTO as well, depending on the indexes and locks (like TABLOCK).

Comment: On the same instance, use the methods mentioned above. As for the other tools, the excel at moving data _between_ instances. The reason `SqlBulkCopy` and SSIS are still the gold standard is they're about as optimized as you can get when it comes to transferring SQL Server data. When you have access to the SQL Server source code, you can do optimizations no third party tool can equal.

Comment: @Stu That's what I had read in a couple places as well, but all the most recent Q&As I can find suggest this isn't the case. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41776365 and https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/99367/insert-into-table-select-from-table-vs-bulk-insert

Comment: `INSERT...SELECT...` has been minimally logged for many years, as long as you keep to the Data Loading Guide rules https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/dd425070%28v=sql.100%29 I don't think those answers are quite correct.

Comment: Or essentially: "It seems for the past 15 years the answer has always been to resort to tools external to SQL Server" is simply not true.